# Can't get to initialize Admob Banner

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I have attempted to initialize AdMob banner ads using test id suggested by the documentation but when running the app I get these errors. 
I don't understand where I fail. I have attempted to follow the guide but they are old or they don't work at all.

```
   04-01 18:47:57.454 3538-3538/it.bluebait.adsdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: it.bluebait.adsdemo, PID: 3538
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here: to add a valid  *
* App ID inside the AndroidManifest. Google Ad Manager publishers should     *
* follow instructions here:                       *
******************************************************************************


    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5002)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4594)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4534)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="it.bluebait.adsdemo">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>

    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID");
```

i think you forgot to initialize the sdk. please use the test id in the above code.
you have to initialize the admob sdk before trying to display the banner ads.

Comment: I did it in MainActivity class, in OnCreate methode